# R: Pass a list through a function, create new variable names

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have this list of numbers: `l1<- list(seq(.85, .95, by= .01))`

That I want to pass through this function:

```
f1<- function(a, x){
    .01**(a**(x/max(x)/100))
}
```

I am going to pass it `df$oldVar` and would like it to return 11 different variables, one for each number within `l1`, with a different name for each (e.g., `newVar1`, `newVar2`, etc.).

Where is the appropriate place to insert a `for` loop?

Comment: You probably don't even need a for loop here.  Rather, just pass in a vector and let the operations work in vector mode.  By the way, you never finished the code of your function.

Comment: good catch, thank you!